# Parse JSON response from API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api

I'm new to Angular and having trouble trying to parse a JSON response from this API: http://icd10api.com/?s=C50&desc=long&r=json

in this codepen here: http://codepen.io/FritzAPI/pen/dNZWKZ

which I got working with a hardcoded modified response:

```
function loadVegetables() {
    var veggies = [
        {"Name":"C50","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of breast"},{"Name":"C50.0","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola"},{"Name":"C50.01","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, female"},{"Name":"C50.011","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, right female breast"},{"Name":"C50.012","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, left female breast"},{"Name":"C50.019","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, unspecified female breast"},{"Name":"C50.02","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, male"},{"Name":"C50.021","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, right male breast"},{"Name":"C50.022","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, left male breast"},{"Name":"C50.029","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, unspecified male breast"}
    ];

    return veggies.map(function (veg) {
        veg._lowername = veg.Name.toLowerCase();
        veg._lowertype = veg.Description.toLowerCase();
        return veg;
    });
}
```

but as soon as the response is wrapped in a search array **{"Search":[...]}** this function no longer works.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your hardcoded object is just slightly different than the response from the API. The API returns an object with a Key `Search`. The value of `Search` is what your `veggies` array is imitating. So something like:

```
apiResponse.Search.map(function (veg) {
  veg._lowername = veg.Name.toLowerCase();
  veg._lowertype = veg.Description.toLowerCase();
  return veg;
});
```

Comment: This is returning a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined... http://codepen.io/FritzAPI/pen/LyQYOb

Comment: Took a stab in the dark and this seems to be working: return veggies[0].Search.map

Comment: Interesting. The response from the API is just an object. Somehow you have an array of objects. How are you building up the `veggies` variable?

Comment: The end goal is to actually get the response from the API and not work with this hardcoded variable.

Comment: I was trying to understand the parsing before attempting that part, that's why I was working with this hardcoded variable that matches the API response.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = {"Search":[{"Name":"C50","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of breast"},{"Name":"C50.0","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola"},{"Name":"C50.01","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, female"},{"Name":"C50.011","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, right female breast"},{"Name":"C50.012","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, left female breast"},{"Name":"C50.019","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, unspecified female breast"},{"Name":"C50.02","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, male"},{"Name":"C50.021","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, right male breast"},{"Name":"C50.022","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, left male breast"},{"Name":"C50.029","Description":"Malignant neoplasm of nipple and areola, unspecified male breast"}],"totalResults":"82","Response":"True"};

var res = jsonObj.Search.map(item => { 
  item._lowername = item.Name.toLowerCase();
  item._lowertype = item.Description.toLowerCase();
  return item;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I still had to add the specific array index "veggies[0]" to get this to work: http://codepen.io/FritzAPI/pen/LyQYOb

Comment: Yes because the json provided in plnkr is an array of objects `[{..}]` but here in OP it is only object `{}`.